What is truth in terms of Buddhism?
I heard the New York Times, wrote recently: "truth is bad, truth is inconvenient!"
William Shakespeare once wrote "nothing is good or bad but thinking makes it so". - when we stop thinking it's bliss!
and "all the worlds a stage and all the men and women merely players", that our time on earth is just a play a show, in order to learn.
Rumi wrote "beyond ideas of good and ideas of bad there is a field, I will meet you there."
Buddha is quoted in the Dhammapada as saying, "rely on nothing, until you want nothing!"
Are we all enlightened already, we just haven't realised it yet? As Ramana Maharshi has appeared to indicate.
I heard a person recently state "forgiveness is one of the highest forms of love". Could truth and silence be higher?


I heard the New York Times, wrote recently: "truth is bad, truth is inconvenient!"

This is not Buddhism. This sounds like political correctness and is not Buddhism. In Buddhism, any bad inconvenient truth conveniently nurtures disenchantment, dispassion & liberation from the world. In Buddhism, truth is always convenient.

William Shakespeare once wrote "nothing is good or bad but thinking makes it so". - when we stop thinking it's bliss!

This is not Buddhism. The Buddha taught to know evil; and then become dispassionate towards evil (Iti 39). Buddhism never abandons the moral perceptions of good & evil. Buddhism simply develops non-attachment towards good & evil.

and "all the worlds a stage and all the men and women merely players", that our time on earth is just a play a show, in order to learn.

This sounds like moral nihilism and is a wrong view in Buddhism (MN 60).

Rumi wrote "beyond ideas of good and ideas of bad there is a field, I will meet you there."

Rumi is not Buddhism. While there is certainly a temporary field of bliss/liberation beyond ideas of good & bad (MN 43), this is not the field of the Buddhas. The Buddhas have ended craving rather than ended ideas of good & bad (Iti 44).

Buddha is quoted in the Dhammapada as saying, "rely on nothing, until you want nothing!"

This is unrelated to the other quotes. This purported Dhammapada quote is about not wanting or not craving. This is not about perceptions of good & evil.

Are we all enlightened already, we just haven't realised it yet? As Ramana Maharshi has appeared to indicate.

No. We are not already enlightened. Ramana Maharshi was not a Buddhist.

I heard a person recently state "forgiveness is one of the highest forms of love". Could truth and silence be higher?

Forgiveness can be another heedless narcissistic state of mind. While "immeasurable" forgiveness can certainly free the mind from forms of suffering (MN 43) and while the Buddha highly recommended forgiveness in certain situations (MN 21), it is not related to Buddhist unsurpassed liberation. If we forgive everything, this will lead to a doctrine of inaction, which the Buddha criticised (AN 3.61). The Buddha extensively taught about social morality (DN 31) & social rule of law (DN 27). Despite personally taking it upon himself, offering guarantees to the King, in reforming a mass-murderer in MN 86, the Buddha never inherently argued against punishment for crimes. For example, in MN 86, if the Buddha was unable to reform the mass-murderer, the mass-murderer would have been subject to execution by the King. There a many suttas where the Buddha warned people that crimes, including for sexual adultery, could lead to grave punishments & execution. The Buddha was not Jesus of Nazareth or Martin Luther.

“Again, with sensual pleasures as the cause…men break into houses, plunder wealth, commit burglary, ambush highways, seduce others’
wives, and when they are caught, kings have many kinds of torture
inflicted on them. The kings have them flogged with whips, beaten with
canes, beaten with clubs; they have their hands cut off, their feet
cut off, their hands and feet cut off; their ears cut off, their noses
cut off, their ears and noses cut off; they have them subjected to the
‘porridge pot,’ to the ‘polished-shell shave,’ to the ‘Rāhu’s mouth,’
to the ‘fiery wreath,’ to the ‘flaming hand,’ to the ‘blades of
grass,’ to the ‘bark dress,’ to the ‘antelope,’ to the ‘meat hooks,’
to the ‘coins,’ to the ‘lye pickling,’ to the ‘pivoting pin,’ to the
‘rolled-up palliasse’; and they have them splashed with boiling oil,
and they have them thrown to be devoured by dogs, and they have them
impaled alive on stakes, and they have their heads cut off with
swords—whereby they incur death or deadly suffering. Now this too is a
danger in the case of sensual pleasures, a mass of suffering here and
now…the cause being simply sensual pleasures.
“Again, with sensual
pleasures as the cause, sensual pleasures as the source, sensual
pleasures as the basis, the cause being simply sensual pleasures,
people indulge in misconduct of body, speech, and mind. Having done
so, on the dissolution of the body, after death, they reappear in
states of deprivation, in an unhappy destination, in perdition, even
in hell. Now this is a danger in the case of sensual pleasures, a mass
of suffering in the life to come, having sensual pleasures as its
cause, sensual pleasures as its source, sensual pleasures as its
basis, the cause being simply sensual pleasures.
MN 13


"No. We are not already enlightened. Ramana Maharshi was not a Buddhist." So what if he wasn't a Buddhist! Buddhist's don't have all the truth. Buddhists can be very fundamentalist, especially to those outside their philosophy! Everyone is enlightened, didn't you know that. "No. Forgiveness is another narcissistic state of mind." no it's not a narcissistic state of mind! It's a beautiful state of mind! Didn't you know that? Don't tell me what is Buddhism and what isn't. You obviously don't know.

Hello. This is a Buddhism forum. Ramana Maharshi zombie meditation has zero relevance to Buddhism. The Buddha himself, prior to his Awakening, abandoned such zombie meditation. Forgiveness is a narcissistic state of mind because it does not consider what is for the benefit & welfare of others. Forgiveness only benefits oneself. The Buddha taught (MN 4) he arose for the benefit & welfare of the many and for the world. Therefore the Buddha gave extensive moral teachings about what is good & evil for the benefit & welfare of the world.

Good bye, you don't know what Buddhism is! Just delete the question is you want, I don't care. You can keep your narrow minded Buddhist forum to yourself!

Dhamma Dhatu - You are a very narrow minded person. Everything is Buddha nature.

Buddhism teaches all conditioned things are impermanent. The Tao De Ching teaches the small are easily scattered.

Actually, it is you, Brendan Darrer, that appears narrow minded. It appears you are unable to accept the truth that Buddhism is different to the ideologies you have posted. It appears you are unwilling to accept diversity. Take care.

Everything is Buddha nature. I don't care what you say, I know myself, I am not narrow minded.

Everything is not Buddha nature. Murder, for example, is not Buddha Nature.

Dhamma Dhatu - I don't think you understand what Buddhism is, it is a beautiful philosophy that everyone can learn from. Not a narrow minded belief structure, that discounts everyone who isn't Buddhist.

"Everything is not Buddha nature. Murder, for example, is not Buddha Nature." Everything is not Buddha nature - many great Buddhist's have said that. "Murder, for example, is not Buddha Nature" - I am not talking about murder, I am talking about the spirit, the whole, but in the bigger picture murder is part of the story, because its a fact of life. "All can know good as good only because there is evil". But obviously we want to remove all evil, so only the Buddha nature remains. Everything is Buddha nature underneath the layers of illusion.

Well, you've heard a lot of thoughts from a lot of people. And when the undisciplined mind hears such thoughts it becomes excited and skittish, like a small bird hopping along the ground: hungry for seeds and wary of dangers. There's nourishment to be found there, but not truth.
If you want truth in the Buddhist sense, you have to pass by what's loud and bright and listen to what's quiet and subtle. You have to step around what's solid and fixed to feel what's fluid and ephemeral. Truth isn't knowing what people say or think (people say and think a lot of things); truth is understanding that which no one can quite put into words.

Truth in terms of Buddhism is knowing what birth is, what life is, what death is, what the universe is, what everything is.
No one can tell you the truth.
You can only know it. You cannot tell it.
Meditate on this:
If somebody told you the truth, it wouldn't be the truth. Why is this so? As soon as somebody tells you the truth, there must be a "knower". Meditate and contemplate: Is there a "knower"? Meditate and see it by yourself: no "knower" can be found.
If somebody told you a lie, it wouldn't be a lie. Why is this so? As soon as somebody tells you a lie, there must be a "knower". Meditate and contemplate: Is there a "knower"? Meditate and see it by yourself: no "knower" can be found.
Nobody can tell the truth. Telling it would be an "approximation".
Meditate and ask: who am I?
Find the answer. Really find it.
Is there an I?
Don't answer there is no I because somebody told you there is no I. Meditate, see the truth and "no answer" will be the answer.
"Who am I?" that's what you must find out.
Once you "know", no word nor nothing else is needed to be said.
See these suttas on how to meditate:
Samadhi
Kayagata-sati Sutta
Anapanasati Sutta
Satipatthana Sutta
Maha-satipatthana Sutta
Saṅkhitta Dhamma Sutta
Dhatu-vibhanga Sutta
Girimananda Sutta
Immersion

Hello. What is birth? what is death? Thanks

I had a very good teacher. I practiced meditation daily for long hours for a very long time, until I was able to reach samadhi without efforts. Then, when out of samadhi, I really slowly went into samadhi and observed very carefully. Then, when in samadhi, really slowly come out of samadhi and observed very carefully. Doing so will give the answer. You can see the links in my edited answer on how to develop samadhi.

hi. your comment appears very questionable to me because none of the links to Pali suttas you posted refer to a "Who Am I?" meditation. In Buddhism, practitioners do not declare any imagined attainments.

A good teacher is key.

You did not answer the question of  What is birth? what is death?

I forgot to mention that deep samadhi is also very important.

You did not answer the question of What is birth? what is death?

You seems to be too confused about the Truth in Buddhism.
Remember the three following Truths , if not others:

Sabbe Sankhara Annica. Meaning all conditioned phenomena are impermanent.
Sabbe Sankhara Dukkha. Meaning all conditioned phenomena are suffering.
Sabbe Dhamma Anatta. Meaning all phenomena are not self.

Whether Buddha arises or not the above three truths are invariably true. Understand them and you understand the Truth in Buddhism.

No, I am not confused about Buddhism, it is a beautiful philosophy that has helped me a lot in my life. I am not a Buddhist though, I don't know what I am, I guess I'm a human being. The sense of not knowing I find helpful.

@BrendanDarrer Then why are you posting nonsense like Truth is bad , Truth is inconvenient?

I don't believe truth is bad! You need to read the answer.
